# Why mu-stratifications?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, sheaf-theory, stratifications, local-systems, singular-support

In the microlocal theory of sheaves developed by Kashiwara and Schapira, there is the notion of a **$\mu$-stratification**, which is a stratification satisfying a stronger property ("$\mu$") than Whitney's conditions A and B.

> How is this "$\mu$" condition used foundationally in the development of microlocal sheaf theory?  Why is it useful to assume a stratification is $\mu$ rather than just Whitney A and B?